# Changing requested authentication scopes - Firebase OIDC Authentication Swift iOS

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, openid-connect

I am currently trying to implement the OpenID Connect Authentication via Firebase with my custom authentication provider. The problem is that when I try to specify the requested scopes in code with `authProvider.scopes = ["roles"]` my provider always shows that (instead of the scopes that I specified) the following scopes seem to be requested from my provider: ["roles", "email", "profile"]. The scopes "email" and "profile" just seem to appear in the process somehow with me not having any influence on that.

In the Google Developer Documentation it says the following before showing further details on changing the requested scopes: "Specify additional custom OAuth parameters that you want to send with the OAuth request." The problem I see here with this is that one can only specify additional scopes to the ones firebase provides you with by default but seems to not being able to change the default scopes that Firebase somehow automatically specifies for this process.

My authentication provider is a German education institute named "IServ". They support Single-Sign-On and OpenID Authentication (German Documentation: https://doku.iserv.de/development/oauth/).
I am not creating an access or identity token directly in my code, I just use the code that firebase has provided in their documentation for this:

```
var authProvider = OAuthProvider(providerID: "oidc.iserv")

authProvider.scopes = ["roles"]

authProvider.getCredentialWith(nil) { credential, error in
// No error or credential returned here, the error is shown in the WebView
}
```

This leads to me having issues with my provider because my provider doesn't grant my application access to the scopes "email" and "profile" and I can't remove them with the help of my code.

I would really appreciate help regarding this problem.

Comment: Are you creating an **access token** or an **identity token**? Who is the provider? Add more details and context to your question. In Google OAuth the scope `openid` includes the scope `email` and I think `profile` as well. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes

Comment: Dear John, Thank you for your answer. I have just updated my question with the provider details and the actual code I use for Authentication.

Comment: Your provider is creating an Identity Token. I am not familiar with that Identity Provider so I cannot help further. Note: your provider's example shows profile, email, and openid. I am not sure what you mean by those are not supported.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far, I basically mean that my provider does not grant me access to these scopes because of their data policy. These scopes have been disabled for my application from the admin panel of my provider.

Comment: That does not make sense. Speak to your provider. The purpose of an Identity Token is to provide **identity**.